# How to do md-content 100% height?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to stretch the content area of the page to 100%
It works fine but if i add

```
layout="column"
```

to body tag it breakes

```
<body layout="column">    
<md-toolbar></md-toolbar>      
        <ui-view></ui-view>
...
</body>
```

and page

```
<div layout-fill layout="row">
  <md-content class="red"  flex layout-align="center center" layout="column">
      <md-card>100% height</md-card>
   </md-content> 
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/H9yVGWrkxeO8Of1NROvY?p=preview

I can't to remove layout="column" because i need page without scroll
 Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Set the proper height of the `ui-view`.
You need to remove the height of the toolbar form the ui-view.

```
ui-view > div.layout-fill {
  min-height: calc(100% - 64px);
}
```

Comment: I added your answer to the plunkr's css and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Try with vh instead of %.  For example, calc(100vh - 64px).  May be acceptable depending on your needs.